# find a special group

Tags: group-theory

Could anyone show me a virtually-nilpotent ( finitely generated, countable discrete) group $G$ such that $G$ is neither finite-by-nilpotent nor virtually abelian?

Thanks!

---

Remarks:

1, By a [result](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2046048&fileId=S0305004100031662) of P.Hall, a finite-by-nilpotent group is virtually-nilpotent; the converse is not true, as seen by the virtually abelian group $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for instance the affine Coxeter group $\tilde A_n, n\ge 5$ (a semidirect product  $Z^n\rtimes S_n$) and, the integer Heisenberg group $H_n$, and multiply them:
$$
G= \tilde A_n \times H_n. 
$$